# Why TableView is empty

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

There are two ViewControllers in the app. The first one has a WebView and a Navigation Bar on top, the second one is a TableView to show URLs visited. Please see screenshots and codes. After I clicked *Save* button to save current URL user is visiting, the TableView is empty. I have tested the TableView first, it is set up fine. Please help to find out the problem.  By the way,  `var savedURLs = [String]( I didn't put the other half of bracket as it won't show correctly if I put it.)`

[image: WebView Controller]

[image: TableView Controller]

```
import UIKit

class BrowserViewController: UIViewController {


  @IBOutlet weak var browser: UIWebView!


  @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let currentURL = browser.request?.URL?.absoluteString  {

        savedURLs.append(currentURL)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: "savedURLs")

    }

  }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

      let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

      browser.loadRequest(request)

  }

}
```

---

```
import UIKit

var savedURLs = [String](

class SavingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var savingTableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   savingTableView.delegate = self
    savingTableView.dataSource = self

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedURLs") != nil {

        savedURLs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedURLs") as! [String]
    }

  }



  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return savedURLs.count
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SavingCell")

    cell!.textLabel?.text = savedURLs[indexPath.row]

    return cell!

  }


  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    savingTableView.reloadData()

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't declare a variable used as table view data source outside a class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Please check the currentURL is not nil. Because of empty  currentURL your tableview is empty.
I suggest you to Saved the urls in NSuserdefault after webview loading finished completely. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I added codes to print currentURL and nothing shows and happens. I waited a while before clicking "Save", still didn't work. WebView doesn't have the window to show url as your screenshot. How to add that window so user can also enter new website directly? Thanks.

Comment: Above attached screen shot is not a window. It's a tableview loaded with currentURL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this function:

```
func reloadTable() {
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedURLs") != nil {
        savedURLs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedURLs") as! [String]
    }
    savingTableView.reloadData()
}
```

And call that one instad of `savingTableView.reloadData()`

Also debug the code by printing the value of variables at some points. For example the new data when you read from `NSUserDefaults` and the value of savedURLs in `viewDidAppear`.

If that doesn't work make sure you're using the right cell identifier:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SavingCell")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried everything you suggested but still nothing shows. So I add codes to print currentURL, nothing shows and happens at console. I think I didn't get the currentURL. Can you help to fix this? By the way, I also printed savedURLs.count, it is 0 and printed for 5 times.

Comment: @Mike Can you upload the project so we can test it?

Comment: @vadian Ah! Thanks you, updating my question

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the data to the next view controller when you click on send button rather than using NSUserDefaults.
Maintain an array by appending the URLs that you visit, then pass it to the next view controller when you click on send.